# Formulas are not calculating after password protecting a sheet

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel

Does anyone know why after password protecting an excel document, and by only ticking the 'select unlocked cells' option, the saved document will not automatically calculate the formulas once is re-opened. 
You then need to go into the 'formula' tab + 'calculate options' and click on 'Automatic' in order to make the sheet calculates all formulas. Can anyone help?

Comment: Which version of Excel?

Answer (score 0):

Check the settings for Formulas in the Excel Options - the defaul setting may have been changed.

In 2010 go to the Home Tab> Options> Formulas > and select Workbook Calculations> "Automatic" radio button under the Calculations Options.

In Excel 2007 Office Button> Options> Formulas> etc